# facing problem in handling route on pressing browser back button

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-routing, angular7

How we can handle route in Angular using browser back button  ,

on pressing back button I want browser should not route back page

for example ..

**

- we go page A to B
- then we can't go back to page A
- on pressing browser Back button

**

I tried with Activateroute in Angular , bit this is giving a alert box on pressing back button , I dont want this , I just want to skip the page on pressing back button .

**I also tried with pushState and popState but this process catch  history still catching route history , I don't want that my rote should exist in browser history**

Comment: So which route do you want to navigate? or you want to stay back in the same route?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427689/angular-5-remove-route-history/51429799#51429799

Comment: @AmitChigadani no I dont want to go to same route instead of that I want to go the home page

Comment: In that case you may have to implement [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) Guard against the current route and then navigate to `/home` from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPopState method of handling back event something like this.

```
location.onPopState(() => {

    console.log('pressed back!');

});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381814/how-do-i-detect-user-navigating-back-in-angular2) stackoverflow question might help you.

Comment: I tried this but browser history still catching route history  , I don't want that my rote should exist in browser history

Answer (score 0):

These are two different ways for handling your use case.

1.

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
```

2.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

Comment: I tried this but browser history still catching route history  , I don't want that my rote should exist in browser history