# Angular: remove all navigation history

Tags: angular, url, navigation, router

After I log the user out it takes her to login path '/' and deletes all the session variables. But then the user can hit the back button in the browser and be redirected back into the app (without any session variables etc). How can I remove all the navigation history so that there is no back button functionality in the browser?

This answer works but only for one level deep. If you press back twice, then it will take you to the app. So this is NOT the answer.
[Angular 5: remove route history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427689/angular-5-remove-route-history)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Browser back button in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357204/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```